# Which aircraft are 76A, 76B, 77E, 77F?

Tags: aircraft-identification, boeing, boeing-777

I have a list of of aircraft types like so:

```
0      320
1      76B
2      DH4
3      E95
4      319
5      76A
6      321
7      77F
8      CR9
9      77E
10     OAAG
```

I was able to identify most of them:

- 320: Airbus A320
- DH4: Bombardier DHC8-Q400/Q400CC (DH4)
- E95: Embraer ERJ-195
- 319: Airbus A319
- 321: Airbus A321
- CR9: Bombardier CRJ-900

However there are some that I cannot understand exactly which model they are. I guess they are Boeing 767 and 777 but I am not sure which model.
Can you help me out to find out which aircraft are these:

- 76A
- 76B
- 77F
- 77E
- OAAG

Comment: Where did you get the list from? As far as I can see, the codes are neither ICAO nor IATA codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are mostly IATA type designators, except for OAAG, 76A, 76B and 77E.

77F is the official IATA designation of the freighter version of the 777.

The rest:

77E *seems* to be an internal designation used by British Airways for a specific sub-fleet with an increased gross weight.

76B *seems* same as above just for 767-300ER.

I wasn't able to find anything about 76A (but I'd guess that same as above) and OAAG (perhaps it is part of the registration of an individual aircraft)

Answer (score 2):

For most accurate information, you can check the following [link](https://cfapp.icao.int/Doc8643/reports/Part2-By%20Type%20Designator(Decode).pdf)
from: IATA PART 2 — AIRCRAFT TYPE DESIGNATORS (DECODE)

As noted in previous answers, 76A, 76B, 77E and OAAG, those are not IATA aircraft codes, hence must be some internal codification for some airlines.

Also wikipedia offers a best view of the whole list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aircraft_type_designators) but for latest information, the first link comes direct from IATA's site (most updated and reliable version).

Best,